# How to re structure the array dynamic way?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, format

**Below is the array format which I have currently**

> There are multiple categories like this, this is one of provided for example

```
[
   {
      "itemId":"123",
      "itemName":"name 1",
      "category":"electric",
      "salePersonName":"person name 1"
   },
   {
      "itemId":"234",
      "itemName":"name 2",
      "category":"electric",
      "salePersonName":"person name 2"
   }{
      "itemId":"345",
      "itemName":"name 3",
      "category":"electric",
      "salePersonName":"person name 3"
   }
]
```

**But I need to restructure it to the below format, how can I do this in a dynamic way**,

```
[
   {
      "category":"electric",
      "items":[
         {
            "temId":"123",
            "itemName":"name 1"
         },
         {
            "itemId":"234",
            "itemName":"name 2"
         },
         {
            "itemId":"345",
            "itemName":"name 3"
         }
      ],
      "salePersons":[
         {
            "salePersonName":"person name 1"
         },
         {
            "salePersonName":"person name 2"
         },
         {
            "salePersonName":"person name 3"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

> Below is code, which I have tried before, but is not giving expected output

```js
   

 

const array = [{
    "itemId": "123",
    "itemName": "name 1",
    "category": "electric",
    "salePersonName": "person name 1"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "234",
    "itemName": "name 2",
    "category": "electric",
    "salePersonName": "person name 2"
  }, {
    "itemId": "345",
    "itemName": "name 3",
    "category": "electric",
    "salePersonName": "person name 3"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "34111",
    "itemName": "name 4",
    "category": "newCategory",
    "salePersonName": "person name 5"
  }
];
let result = {};
array.forEach(function(o) {
  result[o.category] = result[o.category] || {};
  result[o.category]['items'] = [{
    "itemId": result[o.itemId],
    "itemName": result[o.itemName]
  }];
  result[o.category]['salePersons'] = [{
    "salePersonName": result[o.salePersonName]
  }];
});

console.log("result", result)
```

Comment: May you share, as a [mcve], the code that you're having trouble with?

Comment: Sorry @evolutionxbox, I cant provide the codebase coz it's a private project, much appreciate, any solutions from your side to rearrange the array format, which I have mentioned above

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm not asking for the project source. Only a [mcve] that shows the code you're having trouble with. StackOverflow is not a place to request someone to write code for you.

Comment: @evolutionxbox updated the post with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Guys nullish assignment is not working in bit older typescript versions, so I have slightly modified the code. here it is.**

```js
const input = [{
    "itemId": "123",
    "itemName": "name 1",
    "category": "electric",
    "salePersonName": "person name 1"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "234",
    "itemName": "name 2",
    "category": "electric",
    "salePersonName": "person name 2"
  }, {
    "itemId": "345",
    "itemName": "name 3",
    "category": "electric",
    "salePersonName": "person name 3"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "456",
    "itemName": "name 5",
    "category": "Toys",
    "salePersonName": "person name 3"
  }
]
const temp = input.reduce((acc, {
  itemId,
  itemName,
  category,
  salePersonName
}) => {
  let entry;
  if (acc[category] != null || acc[category] != undefined) {
    entry = acc[category]
  } else {
    entry = acc[category] = {
      items: [],
      salePersons: []
    }
  }
  entry.items.push({
    itemId,
    itemName
  });
  entry.salePersons.push({
    salePersonName
  });
  return acc;
}, {})

const result = Object.entries(temp).map(([category, data]) => ({
  category,
  ...data
}))

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = [
   {
      "itemId":"123",
      "itemName":"name 1",
      "category":"electric",
      "salePersonName":"person name 1"
   },
   {
      "itemId":"234",
      "itemName":"name 2",
      "category":"electric",
      "salePersonName":"person name 2"
   },{
      "itemId":"345",
      "itemName":"name 3",
      "category":"electric",
      "salePersonName":"person name 3"
   }
]
const temp = input.reduce((acc, {itemId, itemName, category, salePersonName}) => {
  const entry = (acc[category] ??= {items: [], salePersons:[]})
  entry.items.push({ itemId, itemName });
  entry.salePersons.push({ salePersonName });
  return acc;
},{})

const result = Object.entries(temp).map(([category, data]) => ({ category, ...data }))

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what kind of operator is this, "??=" giving error, I'm working with typescript.

Comment: @RaheemMohamed it's the nullish assignment operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work for you.

```
let result = {};
arr.forEach(function(o) {
  result[o.category] = result[o.category] || {};
  result[o.category]['items'] = result[o.category]['items'] || [];
  result[o.category]['items'].push({
    "itemId": o.itemId,
    "itemName": o.itemName
  });
  result[o.category]['salePersons'] = result[o.category]['salePersons'] || [];
   result[o.category]['salePersons'].push({
    "salePersonName": o.salePersonName
  });
});

console.log("result", result);
```